# Why was cho'gath not seen in the top lane much in season 2 competitive play?

Tags: league-of-legends

I haven't seen Cho'gath picked as top lane in tournament games for much of season 2. Is this a "meta thing", or what are the reasons behind this?

Comment: I'm sure it will change with season 3, but I believe the reason has to do with his wave clearing or lackthereof. He also can't push to far cause he has no real escapes, so he makes an easy gank target early on. Since he isn't ranged it presents an obstacle

Comment: The answer is basically: Because there are better picks for top lane. Cho'Gath is not bad but in lane he gets outclassed by a lot of standard top laners while in jungle he has effective utilities for ganks. Writing this as comment since it's not really an answer, though your question is very subjective anyways.

Comment: @Brian What do you mean? Cho'gath is great at clearing waves. He has 2 AoEs, a passive that turns his auto attack into an AE, and restores health / mana on kill.

Comment: @Brian a Skilled Cho'gath can escape most ganks, his silence and knock up will give him ample time to escape long as he has bushes warded, and he is usually very tanky.

Comment: @Paralytic no he cant, other top laners have built in escapes, cho does not. his stomp is too delayed and easily avoidable.

Comment: @RavenDreamer He has aes, but he is a melee champion which puts him at a disadvantage when clearing waves cause he exposes himself to gank

Comment: @Brian dodging a well placed stomp that is between you and your ganker would require flash or some sort of blink otherwise you have to back off easily giving cho plenty of time to make a decent escape

Comment: ive seen countless times where a cho will silence then stomp a champ and proceeding to make a speedy escape

Comment: @Paralytic Many top laners and junglers have speed buffs and short range blinks (without flash). If they flank Cho even slightly he will have no hope of silencing and stomping both. Also, once those two abilities are down he's very vulnerable to damage, so if even one champ closes on him he's going to be in trouble. This is what makes him poor at top lane - he's can't really fight without his spells up, and he's vulnerable to flanking.

Comment: Also, voted to close question since it's pretty localized in time - the next pro match Cho might be heavily featured, who knows.

Comment: @SadlyNot good thing proper warding and not overextending prevents almost everything. a decent ally jungler also helps

Answer (score 4):

The reason as far as I understand it is that he has no good getaway techniques, making him a champion who is much more vulnerable to ganks than other selections.  His only real getaway technique is using his `Q` for a pop-up, but at the pro level this is fairly easy to predict and avoid.  This, in combination with the fact that Cho'gath relies on not dying very often in order to stay competitive (by keeping his `Feast` stacks up) makes him a risky choice at best, and a terrible choice at worst.

However, with the changes in Season 3, which are supposed to give the jungler less overall influence and power in a game, we may see a resurgence of Cho'gath in top lane since the threat won't be quite so high, thus lowering the risk-to-reward ratio.

Comment: i really cant wait for them to balance the jungle role, never been good at jungling myself. i find myself occasionally being pushed into the role and i fail more then i succeed to a veteran jungler and usually costs the game since the other lanes are failing as well.

Comment: TBH with the jungle changes I don't think they're trying to say that you can't pressure as much, I think they're just trying to make it a choice. If there's a cho top lane I would rather sacrifice some jungle gold to make sure he can't keep stacks up.

Comment: @Snuffleupagus My understanding of the Riot posts was that due to their changes, either the jungler will have much less health for ganking or be lower level (due to a slower clear).  That will reduce the risk of ganks significantly, as top laners will continue to farm and level at the same rate.  Of course, that interpretation is based on their vague declarations about their intentions for the jungle, so it could be way off. :)

Comment: @Jeff Certainly, my comment is of course purely speculation. Some champions certainly won't be able to (lee sin, for example) but others starting with the machete have an ez breezy clear.

Comment: @Jeff The changes they will make to the jungle shouldn't slow down the jungle only make it harded...They want to close the xp and gold gap bettween the jungler and other lanes and make the jungle scales more with late game increasing gold reward but make it harder by increasing monsters damages and AI focusing. It will result in a boring game by breaking the dynamic of early ganks cause it will no longer worth the time it cost.As a jungler i think i will now spend much more time at coutering the other jungler than ganking bacause he will get low much faster and leave alone no brain farm lanes.